# Помощь по Proxy ECMA 2015

Tags: javascript, proxy

Прошу кто сможет объяснить как осуществить решение такой задачи:

Есть страница, неважно пустая или нет, это сути не имеет.
Имеется анонимная функция:

```
(function () {
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = 'https://google.logo';
        document.head.appendChild(img);
})();
```

Она грузит произвольную картинку.
Нужно написать код, который может быть вставлен **ТОЛЬКО ПЕРЕД анонимной функцией**, который подменит `src`, и который должен работать в IE8.

**p.s. Реализация через `window.onload` не подходит, реализация должна происходить через `Proxy` перехватом во время присвоения `img.src`**

Comment: `Proxy` и IE8 - это взаимоисключающие варианты.

Comment: вот и я понимаю это, но я начал плакать когда мне дали такое задание я сразу написал сюда, ибо может я что то не так понял, но даже если упустить возможность реализации на IE8, то всё равно как? ибо я как не пытался, не получалось (потому что я даже не джун)

Answer (score 3):

```
var srcDescr = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLImageElement.prototype, 'src');
var setter = srcDescr.set;

src.set = function(val) {
  /* do all what you need */ 

  setter.call(this, val)
};

Object.defineProperty(HTMLImageElement.prototype, 'src', srcDescr);
```

Comment: это я так понимаю через сеттер будет работать?
я просто не совсем понял что должно будет произойти в коде, ведь он будет должен находится перед выполнением функции, как же он перехватит это действие?

Comment: @Increment будет работать через сеттер. Внутри своего нового сеттера,  нужно будет заменить/изменить значение переданное в функцию и передать его оригинальному сеттеру